# VBA Excel return value from other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

please look at this picture

[image]

for that thing I use VBA like this

```
Sub TransformTbl()
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, cnt As Long

   With ActiveSheet
      .Range("G1:I1") = Array("Date", "Event", "Place")
      cnt = 1
      For j = 2 To 4     
         For i = 2 To 5   
            If Len(.Cells(i, j)) <> 0 Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               .Cells(cnt, 7) = .Cells(1, j)  
               .Cells(cnt, 8) = .Cells(i, j)  
               .Cells(cnt, 9) = .Cells(i, 1)  
            End If
         Next i
      Next j
   End With
End Sub
```

But it work in the same sheet. How can i make the table in the right in the sheet B? but the source (left table) in sheet A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TransformTbl()
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, cnt As Long, ShtB as worksheet, ShtA as Worksheet

   set ShtA = Thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet A")
   set ShtB = Thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet B") ' change to your sheet name

   With ShtA ' change to your sheet name
      ShtB.Range("G1:I1") = Array("Date", "Event", "Place")
      cnt = 1
      For j = 2 To 4     
         For i = 2 To 5   
            If Len(ShtA.Cells(i, j)) <> 0 Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               ShtB.Cells(cnt, 7) = ShtA.Cells(1, j)  
               ShtB.Cells(cnt, 8) = ShtA.Cells(i, j)  
               ShtB.Cells(cnt, 9) = ShtA.Cells(i, 1)  
            End If
         Next i
      Next j
   End With
End Sub
```

You might try this. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach, using a UDF as an in-cell function to work out which entry should be shown depending on the position of the calling cell.

The logic is that the *nth* row in the output table will contain the event data for the *nth* non-blank entry in the source table. So, if we define a UDF that can work out which row of the table it has been called from, then it can establish which cell in the source table contains the non-blank entry to be shown in the row. Once we know the cell, then we also know the corresponding date and place, as these are the column and heading rows respectively.

The parameters to the UDF are 1) the source table area that contains the events (excluding the row and column headings) and 2) the heading cell at the top of the column above the cell making the call. The relative position of the calling cell with respect to the heading cell gives the row. The text in the heading cell is one of "Date", "Event" or "Place", which tells the UDF what data to return.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetEventData(EventTable As Range, ColumnHead As Range)
    Dim iEventNumber As Integer

    '// Calculate which row of the output table this has been called from.
    '// This gives the event number that we need to find in the table
    iEventNumber = Application.Caller.Row - ColumnHead.Row

    '// Check if the event number is bigger than the total possible
    '// number of events - there cannot be any event to return
    If iEventNumber > EventTable.Cells.Count Then
        GetEventData = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    '// The event cell to be found in the event table
    Dim oEventCell As Range

    '// Control variables
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim icol As Integer

    Dim iEventCount As Integer
    iEventCount = 0

    '// Find the nth non-blank entry, where n
    '// is the row number of the caller in the
    '// ouptut table

    For icol = 1 To EventTable.Columns.Count
        For iRow = 1 To EventTable.Rows.Count

            '// Check if the cell contains data,
            '// if so increment the event count
            If Not IsEmpty(EventTable.Cells(iRow, icol)) Then
                iEventCount = iEventCount + 1

                '// After incrementing the count, check if this now
                '// matches the required event number
                If iEventCount = iEventNumber Then
                    Set oEventCell = EventTable.Cells(iRow, icol)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next iRow

        '// Exit the loop if the cell has been found
        If Not oEventCell Is Nothing Then Exit For

    Next icol

    '// Check if there was no event found corresponding
    '// to this row number
    If oEventCell Is Nothing Then
        GetEventData = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    '// Now check what data item we need to return,
    '// depending on the column heading
    Select Case ColumnHead.Value
    Case "Date"
        '// Return the date heading in the same column as the source data cell
        GetEventData = EventTable.Cells(0, oEventCell.Column - EventTable.Column + 1).Value

    Case "Event"
        '// Return the content of the event cell itself
        GetEventData = oEventCell.Value

    Case "Place"
        '// Return the place name from the same row as the source data cell
        GetEventData = EventTable.Cells(oEventCell.Row - EventTable.Row + 1, 0).Value

    Case Else
        '// Not recognised data item
        GetEventData = ColumnHead.Value & "?"

    End Select

End Function
```

This approach has the advantage that the output table updates as soon as any entry is changed in the input area, the input and output tables can be in different sheets or even different workbooks. And you can use the same UDF for as many different event tables as you like.

This is how it looks in use:

[image]

Comment: wow thank you, I'm definitely gonna learn more about your way of doing this